# How to set a value for pack.windowMemory?

Tags: git

I am trying to limit the amount of memory that `git gc --aggressive` is using. I set `pack.windowMemory` to 8 GB to do that:

```
git config --global pack.windowMemory 8g
```

The config file now correctly shows:

```
[pack]
    windowMemory = 8g
```

The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) shows that this should work.

But `git gc` produces an error:

> $ git gc --aggressive
>
> fatal: bad numeric config value '8g' for 'pack.windowmemory': out of range
>
> fatal: failed to run repack

How can I set `pack.windowMemory`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[pack.windowmemory is a ulong.](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bfdd66e72fffd18235757bedbf355fd4176d6019/builtin/pack-objects.c#L2817)

[`maximum_unsigned_value_of_type(long)`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/99c33bed562b41de6ce9bd3fd561303d39645048/config.c#L959) is 2<sup>32</sup> (32-bit) = 4,294,967,296 ≈ 4 billion.

[`g` suffix is 1,073,741,824.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)
8 × 1,073,741,824 = 8,589,934,592 ≈ 8 billion.

You need to choose a value at most around 4 GB.

Comment: That's it, thanks. The maximum value seems to be `2047m`. Is there a reason the setting does not go higher? I have seen `git gc` use 20 GB of RAM on my machine. I'd like it to use around 8 GB.

Comment: If you're using a 32-bit system or using Windows, then no, there isn't a way around this.  Only on 64-bit Unix systems can you specify a value larger than 2 GiB.  Git should probably switch to use a 64-bit value on 64-bit Windows, but that's a tricky compatibility issue nobody has gotten to yet.

Comment: Note that ULONG_MAX varies from one platform to another.